# django and jQuery autocomplete not working

Tags: jquery, django, autocomplete

I have a form which has input as name. It search the lastname and firstname field in a database. I need to autocomplete when users type the name. I was suggested to use jQuery following this link
[django jquery](http://flaviusim.com/blog/AJAX-Autocomplete-Search-with-Django-and-jQuery/)

But it's not working. I tried all the suggestion in the comments, nothings works. My models

```
class Pitable(models.Model):
pid = models.TextField(db_column='PID', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
lname = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
fname = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
locs = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
doclist = models.TextField(db_column='PMIDlist', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'PItable'
```

My views:

```
import json
def get_people(request):
if request.is_ajax():
    q = request.GET.get('term', '')
    persons = Pitable.objects.filter(lname__icontains = q )[:20]
    results = []
    for person in persons:
        person_json = {}
        person_json['id'] = person.pid
        person_json['label'] = person.lname
        person_json['value'] = person.lname         
        results.append(person_json)
    data = json.dumps(results)
    #data = json.dumps(list(Pitable.objects.filter(lname__icontains=q).values('lname')))
else:
    data = 'fail'
mimetype = 'application/json'
return HttpResponse(data, mimetype)
```

urls:

```
url(r'^api/get_people/', views.get_people, name='get_people'),
```

html:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.18/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">
 </script> <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

 <script>
 $(function() {
 $("#names").autocomplete({
source: "/api/get_people/",
minLength: 2,
});
});
</script>
.......
<div class="ui-widget">
<label for="names">Drugs: </label>
<input id="names">
</div>
```

The runserver side says

```
Not Found: /api/get_people/
[21/Oct/2016 16:36:05] "GET /api/get_people/?term=ra HTTP/1.1" 404 2065
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: First off, please end the regex pattern with `$` `url(r'^api/get_people/$', views.get_people, name='get_people'),`

Comment: Tried it. It's still not working. Same runserver side "Not Found...."

Comment: what does your root url conf look like ?

Comment: `from django.conf.urls import url`

`from . import views` `app_name = 'chinook'`   `urlpatterns = [.....]`

Comment: Could anyone help me? Please!!!